# How is the ampere percentage of a circuit breaker selected for different loads

Tags: current, maximum-ratings

This document below specifies rules according to which a circuit breaker is selected, it specifies Maximum Circuit Breaker Size % of Current for different loads in table 2

http://www.fs.fed.us/database/acad/elec/greenbook/3_basicdesigns.pdf

But what I fail to understand is how are these percentages calculated? What is its formula?
Any kind of help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no formula, not everything in EE is described in formulas. If it was EE would be no fun. If you like formulas, go study maths instead.

The percentages are based on **experience**.

Some devices, like motors and welders can draw a **huge** current when they start up / you switch them on.

Some do not, these are the resistive loads like heaters, ovens and toasters. These draw the current that you would expect from their rating, not more.

So that is why depending on the expected load, a certain trip current is selected.

Comment: On page 1 of that link, 'rule of thumb'. On page 5, different figures for 'motor', and 'non-motor' loads. Experience!